# how to get the Testcase level statistics in rebort framework log?

Tags: robotframework

I would like to see the testcase level statistic in robot framework log. Currently we are getting in "Statistics by Tag" and "Statistic by Suite". However I am looking for "statistic by testcases"

Comment: What sort of statistics? You already get execution times and pass/fail, what else do you need?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am looking for testcase name and status(pass/fail). Typically we will get this info in report file. Similarly in log file too.

Comment: I don't understand. The log contains this information already. How is what you want different from what is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

robot framework doesn't support a summary for test cases like it does for suites and tags.